# mobile responsive code to correct or to remove it

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

Please if someone can review the website www.iibmdxb.com designed by another guy. 
I am trying to fix the mobile responsive it is not working correctly for top header and for the bottom specially also the slider.

i tried to find code to fix it but i could not make it correct. 
also, i tried to remove the mobile responsive from website after deleting the viewport lines but still mobile responsive is active.

here i have the css files for your ref.
http://iibmdxb.com/css/styles.css
http://iibmdxb.com/css/main.css

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here . You need to consider bootstrap column grid model when used along with margin as they occupy space beside these columns.
Dont remove meta viewport, its the first step to responsiveness.
You should also add more view breakpoints.
For the footer , make the footer stick at bottom and give it a margin to the whole document ensuring it doesn't merge.
make use of media queries to keep the desktop view intact.
Try to utilise bootstrap features by floating only to one side , add .text-center to center align objects or make some rules which best fit this scenario.